# How to access toolbar items from ViewModel Xamarin forms

Tags: dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, prism

I tried to set padge in toolbar item from **viewmodel** 
I have interface called `IToolbarItemBadgeService`

```
public interface IToolbarItemBadgeService
    {
        void SetBadge(Page page, ToolbarItem item, string value, Color backgroundColor, Color textColor);
    }
```

I want to set badge in toolbar item i used this code after i Register the interface but it throw exception

```
            private IToolbarItemBadgeService _toolbarItemBadge;
```

and in the **constructor**

```
  public MainTabPageViewModel(IToolbarItemBadgeService toolbarItemBadge)
        {
            _toolbarItemBadge = toolbarItemBadge;
            _toolbarItemBadge.SetBadge(MainTabPage.Main,MainTabPage.Main.ToolbarItems.FirstOrDefault() , $"{BaseService.CartCounter}", Color.Orange, Color.White);
        }
```

**Exception** is thrown :

> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type = 'System.Object', name = 'MainTabPage'.
>   Exception occurred while: Calling constructor
>   LGMobileApp.Views.MainTabPage(). Exception is:
>   ResolutionFailedException - Resolution of the dependency failed, type
>   = 'LGMobileApp.ViewModels.MainTabPageViewModel', name = '(none)'. Exception occurred while: Calling constructor
>   LGMobileApp.ViewModels.MainTabPageViewModel(Prism.Navigation.INavigationService
>   navigationService, LGMobileApp.Helpers.IToolbarItemBadgeService
>   toolbarItemBadge). Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: looks to me like you didn't export IToolbarItemBadgeService

Comment: what do u mean ? can u share sample ?

Comment: Show us the code where you register the implementation of `IToolbarItemBadgeService`

Answer (score 1):

From exception you can see that your service is not registred and it can not be resolved.

You will need to register your `IToolbarItemBadgeService` interface, with implemenation inside of `App.cs` in `RegisterTypes` method.

Something like this:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
      containerRegistry.Register<IToolbarItemBadgeService, ToolbarItemBadgeService>();
      // .. Other registration code
}
```

After this, you will be able to use `IToolbarItemBadgeService` which is injected in your `MainTabPageViewModel`.

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: The problem was that the instance is always null comming from MainTabPage.Main .. thx :)

Comment: @AlmirVuk, Thanks for your answer but how to pass the variables from the ViewModel.SetBadge(Page page,ToolbarItem item, string value,Color   backgroundColor,Color textColor); the view model doesn't know about the ToolBarItem

Comment: I am getting an error 'ToolbarItems' doesn't exists in the current context when I try to call it from the ViewModel

Comment: @Ali123 take an instance from view.cs to viewmodel