# ToolbarItems count is coming as 0 in viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, tabbedpage

i am trying to bind a badge count in the toolbar item from my viewmodel.

But everytime Toolbaritem count is coming as 0 in my viewmodel.when i try same code in the backend c# i am getting count as 1.

Menupage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.MenuPage"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             BarBackgroundColor="White"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor=" #388e3c"
             android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="ic_notifications_active_white.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" Command="{Binding NotificationsNavigateCommand}" />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="dropdown.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="25"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <views:A Title="A" Icon="outline_home_black_18dp.png" />

    <TabbedPage Title="status" Icon="icons8_bar_chart.png">
        <views:B Title="B"></views:B>
        <views:C Title="C"></views:C>
    </TabbedPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

menupageviewmodel.cs

```
public class MenuPageViewModel : ContentPage, INavigatedAware
{
    public MenuPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        LoadCount();
    }

    private async void LoadCount()
    {
        if (ToolbarItems.Count > 0)
            try
            {
                var toolbarservice = DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>();


                toolbarservice.SetBadge(this, ToolbarItems.First(), "1", Color.Red, Color.White);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        //if (ToolbarItems.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        //ToolbarItems =new MenuPage.ToolbarItems();

        //        var toolbarservice = DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>();

        //        toolbarservice.SetBadge(this, ToolbarItems.First(), "1", Color.Red, Color.White);
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        throw ex;
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

i think its loading pblm my view is loading after viewmodel.i tried on prism OnNavigatedFrom also but result is same.one more question related to loading is ,my app taking more time to open because viewmodel for every page is hitting.how to restrict only loading first tab detail page on app opening

Comment: @TheGeneral Can you give a solution for that

Comment: `DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>()` ... this is so wrong

Comment: @ Haukinger i am facing issue on getting ToolbarItems.Count every time its coming as 0. i am trying exactly like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965277/how-to-access-toolbar-items-from-viewmodel-xamarin-forms) but he doesnt specify how to get access to toolbaritems from viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

I guess your project's architecture must be like this:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MenuPage");
```

Make your root tabbed page wrapped by a base navigation page. I don't recommend you to use this hierarchy. It will make all of your pages display the same `ToolbarItems` as you created it on your root tabbed page.

But if you do need to use that, you could let your view model implement the `IPageLifecycleAware` and get the count there:

```
public class MenuPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPageLifecycleAware
{
    public MenuPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        //LoadCount();
    }

    private async void LoadCount()
    {
        NavigationPage navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
        var tabbpedPage = navigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault();
        var count = tabbpedPage.ToolbarItems.Count;

        if (count > 0)
        try
        {
            var toolbarservice = DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>();

            toolbarservice.SetBadge(tabbpedPage, tabbpedPage.ToolbarItems.FirstOrDefault(), "1", Color.Red, Color.White);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        LoadCount();
    }

    public void OnDisappearing()
    {

    }
}
```

However, I still don't recommend you to access the view related stuff in your view model. Moreover, do not make your view model inherit from a ContentView, it makes no sense.

Comment: Like you said i need same tool bar item in every page.I think your code wlll work for me.but without inheriting the contentview in viewmodel ,how  i can i acheive this  toolbarservice.SetBadge(this, tabbpedPage.ToolbarItems.FirstOrDefault(), "1", Color.Red, Color.White); . on this i am getting error as canot convert viewmodel to page

Comment: @ebk If you want to access the current page in your interface, you could use tabbpedPage. `tabbpedPage` is the page which you want to pass.

Comment: your code is working.but when i change the tab i am loosing my badge count.thanks

Comment: @ebk It’s another issue and depends on how you implement it in your interface.

Comment: @ Land Lu - MSFT.ok..i have another issue related to this.i set my root page as navigation like this await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MenuPage"); instead of you given for me in [this](https://github.com/landl0526/PrismTabDemo).so in my second tab(view B&view C) if i navigate to another view say D from B like this _navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(D) i am not getting any navigation bar . thanks

Comment: @ebk I guess you are meaning your toolbar item is missing. Please notice each page has its own toolbar item. The MenuPage's toolbar item is persisted on the window because you just changed its tab. But if you navigate to a new page, the tabbed page's toolbar item will be gone and the new page's own toolbar item will be shown up.

Comment: @ebk Hi, did you have some updates about this issue?